# UrL Rewrite using code with my domain

Tags: .htaccess

URL : `http://domainname.com/index.php?p=top-games`

I need to rewrite this as `http://domainname.com/top-games`

How I do this using htaccess file? Please can any one give me the htaccess code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule
```

Create .htaccess file in your root folder and paste code

Comment: htaccess won't redirect, It is used to rewrite URL like you want. When you run http://domainname.com/top-games, internally URL will be consider like http://domainname.com/index.php?p=top-games

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for redirect in reverse direction.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```